# The following lines were not loaded into QGIS due to errors

Tags: qgis, csv

I have lat and long coordinates of Premier League football stadiums, which I want to map onto a NUTS-2 shapefile.

They are saved in a CSV document, which when I go to upload, not one of my coordinates are read in successfully. Instead the following error occurs:

> The following lines were not loaded into QGIS due to errors

Perhaps someone may know what my issue is?

I have attached a picture for reference.

[image: Image of issue]

Comment: How are your lt and lg columns defined? can you post a screenshot of the original CSV?

Comment: Try unchecking the **DMS coordinates** option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot shows x=lt and y=lg.

Typically X=Longitude and Y=Latitude in QGIS.